# Ember list view (using #each helper and zynga scroller) with delayed content

Tags: ember.js

I'm rendering two lists based on two arrays in my controller. The contents of the first array are added immediately, but the second is populated after a delay of 500ms. The list on top scrolls as expected, but the second (delayed) one doesn't. The delay simulates loading content through an ajax request via Ember data, which has the same effect. Any clues?

The code is available here: http://jsbin.com/owejoz/5/

This is how the list is displayed:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="content_list" data-scrollable="x">
        {{#each content1}}
            <div class="list_item">{{name}}</div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="content_list" data-scrollable="x">
        {{#each content2}}
            <div class="list_item">{{name}}</div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript code is as follows:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   content1: [],
   content2: []
 });

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        var content1 = [];
        var content2 = [];
        for (var j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
            content1.push({name: "Item " + j});
        }
        controller.set('content1', content1);


        setTimeout(function () {
            for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                content2.push({name: "Delayed item " + i});
            }
            controller.set('content2', content2);

        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `setTimeout` to `Ember.run.later` :

```
Ember.run.later(function () {
      for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        content2.push({name: "Delayed item " + i});
      }
      controller.set('content2', content2);

    }, 500);
```

Comment: Changing setTimeout to Ember.run.later doesn't seem to help i.e I'm able to scroll the top list properly (and can see the last item) but the bottom one doesn't scroll properly. The behavior is the same on Firefox and Chrome: http://jsbin.com/owejoz/8

Comment: @user1889776 as soon as I resize the window, the scrolling works again. Not sure why that is though...

Comment: Have you tried to replicate this outside of ember? It almost seems like it my be an issue with the js lib you are using to scroll.

Comment: flynfish, you're right about resizing the window - it works. It works fine without ember i.e when I use a static list of items. I think causes the view to be re-rendered, or something along those lines. It seems like when the view is rendered before the content has been updated (the delayed case), that's when the problem occurs. It's fixed when the view is re-rendered.